# Laravel 3.x Assets: how to include an external url

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-3

I'm trying to include a google CDN jquery link into the Laravel Assets container but the link is being concatenated to my site address, like this:

```
<script src="http://mybeautifulsite.com/<script src=" http:="" ajax.googleapis.com="" ajax="" libs="" jquery="" 1.8.3="" jquery.min.js"=""></script>
```

Is there any way to include external links into the assets container?

**EDIT**

Here's the code I'm using to include the asset:

```
Asset::add('jquery', '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>');
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to generate that script tag.

Comment: @PhillSparks My fault. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should just be:

```php
Asset::add('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
```

Whilst [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/views/assets#registering-assets) does not explicitly talk about absolute URLs, the code is written in such a way to handle them.